# How to safely change deployment target in ios

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.3, deployment-target, base-sdk

I have developed a app using swift 2.2 with Xcode 7.3.1 i have set my deployment target 9.3 and base SDK is also 9.3.Now i want reduce my deployment target to 8.1.what are the proper procedure to change deployment target without affecting any of the Frameworks and libraries or syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way. If you really need to support your deployment target as 8.1 then you should test the application fully on 8.1. This will make sure the availability of all APIs in your minimum OS version.

Comment: i have changed the deployment target to 8.1 and make build and runs on my device without any issue

Comment: Then you can change it..!!

Comment: in project > build settings there is also a deployment target that is 9.3 i want change that or changing in target > general tab is enough